# NodeJS map Dtos to TypeORM Entities

Tags: node.js, dto, nestjs, typeorm, class-transformer

I have a `nodejs` REST API backend running the `nestjs` framework, using **typeORM** as **ORM** for my entities.

Coming from a `C#/Entity Framework` background, I am very used to have my Dtos mapped to the database entities.

Is there a similar approach with typeORM?

I have seen the [automapper-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/automapper-ts) library, but those magic strings in the map declarations look kind of scary...
Basically it would be amazing if I could :

```
let user: TypeORMUserEntity = mapper.map<TypeORMUserEntity>(userDto);
```

What is the way to do this (or any alternative with same result) in nodejs/typeorm backend environment?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [class-transformer](https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer) library. You can use it with [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator) to cast and validate POST parameters.

Example:

```
@Exclude()
class SkillNewDto {
  @Expose()
  @ApiModelProperty({ required: true })
  @IsString()
  @MaxLength(60)
  name: string;

  @Expose()
  @ApiModelProperty({
    required: true,
    type: Number,
    isArray: true,
  })
  @IsArray()
  @IsInt({ each: true })
  @IsOptional()
  categories: number[];
}
```

`Exclude` and `Expose` here are from `class-transform` to avoid additional fields.

`IsString`, `IsArray`, `IsOptional`, `IsInt`, `MaxLength` are from `class-validator`.

`ApiModelProperty` is for Swagger documentation

And then

```
const skillDto = plainToClass(SkillNewDto, body);
const errors = await validate(skillDto);
if (errors.length) {
  throw new BadRequestException('Invalid skill', this.modelHelper.modelErrorsToReadable(errors));
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a DTO -> DTO instead of a DTO -> Enity mapping ?
```typescript
const skillDto = plainToClass(SkillNewDto, body);
```

Answer (score 2):

I am using `create` method from `getRepository`

```
export async function save(booking: CreateBookingDto) {
  const bookingRepository = getRepository(Booking);

  const bookingEntity = bookingRepository.create({ ...booking });
  return bookingRepository.save(bookingEntity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use data-transform-object.

here is example:

```
class LoginResDto {
 token?: string;

 addCustomProperty = (propertyName: AllowedKeys, propertyValue: any): this => {
   this[propertyName] = propertyValue;
   return this;
 };

 @Expose()
 type: UserType;

 @Expose()
 name: string;

 @Expose()
 surname: string;

 @Expose()
 publicId: number;

 @Expose({
   name: 'I',
 })
 @Type(() => HumanResDto)
 detail: HumanResDto;
}

export default LoginResDto;
```

call function:

```
const convertData = TransformService.convert<LoginResDto, UserEntity>(
           userExist,
           LoginResDto,
           'excludeAll'
         ).addCustomProperty('token', tokenInstance.clientToken);
```

TransformService:

```
class TransformService {
  static convert<T, K>(
    source: K,
    destinationClass: ClassConstructor<T>,
    strategy: 'excludeAll' | 'exposeAll'
  ): T {
    return plainToClass(destinationClass, source, { strategy });
  }

  static convertArray<T, K>(
    source: K[],
    destinationClass: ClassConstructor<T>,
    strategy: 'excludeAll' | 'exposeAll'
  ): T[] {
    return plainToInstance(destinationClass, source, { strategy });
  }
}

export default TransformService;
```