# NestJS Do I need DTO's along with entities?

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I am creating simple service, that will do simple CRUD.
So far I have the **entity** user:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  username: string;

  @Column({ name: "first_name" })
  firstName: string;

  @Column({ name: "last_name" })
  lastName: string;

  @Column({ name: "date_of_birth" })
  birthDate: string;
}
```

Controller:

```
import { Controller, Get,  Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Controller('api/v1/backoffice')
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Get(':username')
  findOne(@Query('username') username: string) {
    return this.usersService.findByUsername(username);
  }
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}


  findByUsername(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne({ username });
  }
}
```

With this basic example, I return values from the DB, where some Columns are rename: first_name --> firstName

It does serve my purpose, but on so many places, I see DTO's being used. I know I am not doing correct things, and that I should start using it as well.
How would I use the DTO approach with my example?

I am trying to grasp the concept here.

Comment: It's way easier than you think. Take a look at this example where you can use TypeORM + class-transformer + class-validator in only 3 lines of code -> [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51113506/nodejs-map-dtos-to-typeorm-entities).
There is also a library that can combine both into one single operation - [HERE](https://github.com/MichalLytek/class-transformer-validator).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First thing, @Carlo Corradini 's comment is right, you should have a look at the `class-transformer` and `class-validator` libs, which are also used under the hood in NestJS pipes noticeably and can be nicely combined with `TypeORM`.

#### 1: As per @Carlo Corradini 's comment and its corresponding links

Now, since your DTO instance is the representation of the data you want to expose to your consumer, you have to instantiate it after you have retrieved your user entity.

1. create a new `user-response.dto.ts` file and declare a `UserResponseDto` class inside it that you'll export. Let's say code would look as follows if you want to expose everything from your previously retrieved `User` entity

`user-response.dto.ts`

```js
import { IsNumber, IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';

@Exclude()
export class UserResponseDto {
  @Expose()
  @IsNumber()
  id: number;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  username: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  firstName: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  lastName: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  birthDate: string;
}
```

Here with the @Exclude() at the top of the `UserResponseDto`, we're telling `class-transformer` to exclude any field that doesn't have the `@Expose()` decorator in the DTO file when we'll be instantiating a `UserResponseDto` from any other object.
Then with the `@IsString()` and `@IsNumber()`, we're telling class-validator to validate the given fields' types when we'll validate them.

2. Cast your User entity into a `UserResponseDto` instance:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}


  async findByUsername(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    const retrievedUser = await this.usersRepository.findOne({ username });

    // instantiate our UserResponseDto from retrievedUser
    const userResponseDto = plainToClass(UserResponseDto, retrievedUser);

    // validate our newly instantiated UserResponseDto
    const errors = await validate(userResponseDto);
    if (errors.length) {
        throw new BadRequestException('Invalid user',
this.modelHelper.modelErrorsToReadable(errors));
    }
    return userResponseDto;
  }
}
```

#### 2: Another way of achieving it:

You could also use the [`ClassSerializerInterceptor` interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/serialization) from ***@nestjs/common*** to automatically cast your returned `Entity` instances from services into the proper returned type defined in your controller's method. This would mean that you wouldn't even have to bother with using plainToClass within your service and let the job get done by Nest's interceptor itself, with a slight detail as stated by the official docs

> Note that we must return an instance of the class. If you return a
> plain JavaScript object, for example, { user: new UserEntity() }, the
> object won't be properly serialized.

Code would look as follows:

`users.controller.ts`

```js
import { ClassSerializerInterceptor, Controller, Get,  Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Controller('api/v1/backoffice')
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor) // <== diff is here
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Get(':username')
  findOne(@Query('username') username: string) {
    return this.usersService.findByUsername(username);
  }
}
```

`users.service.ts`

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository, getRepository } from 'typeorm';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private readonly usersRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}


  async findByUsername(username: string): Promise<User | undefined> {
    return this.usersRepository.findOne({ username }); // <== must be an instance of the class, not a plain object
  }
}
```

*Last thoughts*:
With the latest solution, you could even use the `class-transformer`'s decorators within your User entity file and don't have to declare the DTO file, but you would lose the data validation.

Let me know if it helps or if something is unclear :)

### EDIT with incoming payload validation & transformation into proper DTO

You would declare a `GetUserByUsernameRequestDto` with a username attribute in it, like so:
`get-user-by-username.request.dto.ts`

```js
import { IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { Exclude, Expose } from 'class-transformer';

@Exclude()
export class GetUserByUsernameRequestDto {
  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  username: string;
}
```

`users.controller.ts`

```js
import { ClassSerializerInterceptor, Controller, Get,  Query } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UsersService } from './users.service';

@Controller('api/v1/backoffice')
@UseInterceptors(ClassSerializerInterceptor) // <== diff is here
@UsePipes( // <= this is where magic happens :)
    new ValidationPipe({
        forbidUnknownValues: true,
        forbidNonWhitelisted: true,
        transform: true
    })
)
export class UsersController {
  constructor(private readonly usersService: UsersService) {}

  @Get(':username')
  findOne(@Param('username') getUserByUsernameReqDto: GetUserByUsernameRequestDto) {  
    return this.usersService.findByUsername(getUserByUsernameReqDto.username);
  }
}
```

Here we're using [Nest's pipes concept](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) - @UsePipes() - to get the job done. along with built-in `ValidationPipe` from Nest as well.
You can refer to the docs both from [Nest](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#class-validator) and [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#usage) themselves to learn more about the options to pass to the `ValidationPipe`

So this way your incoming params and payload data can be validated before being processed :)

Comment: Thank you for your time and great explanation. After playing it around, I have come to the same conclusion. Since this is a only search controller, I could do it without DTO, but I need validation on the username property (from the user), and only way I could achieve it is with validation class in DTO.

Comment: alright, then it's the incoming DTO that needs to be validated, the returned DTO might not need to be validated, but only instantiated with the proper fields you want to expose. I'll edit my answer with the use of Pipes to validate and transform the incoming payload into a DTO

Comment: Wish I could upvote your answer several times. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm looking for a solution to have Entity - serializer and validator definition in one place without having trouble if a field is added to entity and update all dtos.